# Not sure how to make CSS box positioning relative for resize/zoom

Tags: css, css-position, box

I have zero experience in HTML of CSS and have been trying to create a blog - http://ics.restlessrayner.com/. I made a heading image, but wanted to make two specific areas of said image clickable. To do this I thought I'd make two transparent boxes, I called them box-link for the red one, and box-link2 for the yellow. They have the right position when viewing in my browser, however on larger monitors or when resizing the page they do not scale appropriately and lose their correct position. I've tried my best to find a solution or to try and understand the relative positioning command, but alas it seems beyond the realms of my current abilities.

Here's the code:

```
    <div class='box-wrap'> 
    <div class='box-wrap1'>
            <a href='http://ics.restlessrayner.com/p/other-blogs.html' id='box-link'/>
            <p/>
            </div>
    <div class='box-wrap1'>
            <a href='http://ics.restlessrayner.com/' id='box-link2'/>
            <p/>
            </div>
```

And the CSS:

```
    #box-link {
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    left: 725px;
    width: 210px;
    height: 65px;
    background-color: red;
    border: 3px solid transparent; }

    #box-link2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 40px;
    width: 500px;
    height: 70px;
    background-color: yellow;
    border: 3px solid transparent; }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need that it should behave properly when viewing in different resolution, which in turn means you want a responsive website. So you should go for framework such  as twitter bootstrap. It is a grid system that helps to build a responsive website. Else you have to write media queries for the entire frame (a bit complicated if you are a newbie). Hence it is better to go with Twitter Bootstrap. Few documentation on there website will help you with its usage.